# Binary conditional operator with assignment

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, operators

I have this code in javascript:

`val: a ? a : ''`

Basically checking that `a` is not null before assinging it.

The problem is that `a` is double in the line.
Is there a shorter way to do this like:

`val: a ? ''`

?
Thanks

Comment: How about `a ?? ""`? The semantics are different though: `a ? a : ""` isn't checking if `a` is not null, it's checking if `a` is falsey which happens to include null. `a ?? ""` is also checking undefined in addition to null. You may want `a === null ? "" : a` for maximum precision.

Comment: with or `val: a || ''`

Comment: You can  const val = a || ' ';